# How to store unsigned int value to unsigned char variable?

Tags: c, unsigned-integer, unsigned-char

Suppose I have

```c
unsigned int x = 0x12a
unsigned char y = 0x000
```

How can I make `x = y`? When I try to assign x to y, i get `y = 0x02a`

Comment: The maximum value of unsigned char is `0xff`. It's not possible to store `0x12a` there.

Comment: Why are you using `unsigned char` if you need more than 8 bits?

Comment: @Barmar thank you. I didn't know about that. I am just experimenting stuff for my project.